# Draw Marker on Click in openstreetmap android

Tags: android, location, openstreetmap, marker

I am new to Open Street Map map. I want to put the marker on map where i Tapped. I want to delete previous marker also. Please help me. Thanks in advance. Here is my code. I am struggling from 2 days in this Problem Please.

```
Overlay touchOverlay = new Overlay(this) {
 ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay = null;

 @Override
 protected void draw(Canvas arg0, MapView arg1, boolean arg2) {

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(final MotionEvent e,
 final MapView mapView) {
 Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
 GeoPoint loc = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) e.getX(),
 (int) e.getY());
 String longitude = Double
 .toString(((double) loc.getLongitudeE6()) / 1000000);
 String latitude = Double
 .toString(((double) loc.getLatitudeE6()) / 1000000);
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude:"
 + longitude + " Latitude: " + latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast.show();
 ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
 OverlayItem mapItem = new OverlayItem("", "", new GeoPoint(
 (((double) loc.getLatitudeE6()) / 1000000),
 (((double) loc.getLongitudeE6()) / 1000000)));

 mapItem.setMarker(marker);
 overlayArray.add(mapItem);
 if (anotherItemizedIconOverlay == null) {
 anotherItemizedIconOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
 getApplicationContext(), overlayArray, null);
 mapView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
 mapView.invalidate();
 } else {
 mapView.getOverlays().remove(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
 mapView.invalidate();
 anotherItemizedIconOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
 getApplicationContext(), overlayArray, null);
 mapView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
 }
 return true;
 }

 };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location change and put Marker on Click in openstreetmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403420/location-change-and-put-marker-on-click-in-openstreetmap)

Comment: its also mine code. its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i ge solutions of this problem. Here is my solution.

```
@Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {

        Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
        p = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
         proj = mapView.getProjection();
         loc = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
         String longitude = Double
         .toString(((double) loc.getLongitudeE6()) / 1000000);
         String latitude = Double
         .toString(((double) loc.getLatitudeE6()) / 1000000);
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "Longitude: "
         + longitude + " Latitude: " + latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
        return true;
    }

private void addLocation(double lat, double lng) {
    // ---Add a location marker---

    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));

    Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(
            android.R.drawable.star_big_on);

    int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();

    marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

    ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(
            getApplicationContext());

    myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);

    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(myItemizedOverlay);

    mapView.invalidate();
}
```